# Nginx proxy pass configuration

Tags: nginx

I am trying to add below proxy pass in nginx

```
location /pattern {
   proxy_pass http://othervip.com/;
}
```

My expectation is that when I hit http://myvip.com/pattern/api/call the request should get proxied to http://othervip.com/api/call  (without the 'pattern')

However, this is not working, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try `location /pattern/ { ... }`

Comment: @RichardSmith Can you please give more clarity or point me to a documentation link on this.

Comment: Your question is too broad to answer definitively, but there is an obvious error - which is a missing trailing `/` on the `location` value. `nginx` replaces text in the URI from "/pattern" with "/", so "/pattern/foo" becomes "//foo", which may or may not be the cause of the problem. See [this link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass).